# Wicket.Ajax: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "radioGroup1d" because the element is not in the DOM

Tags: java, wicket, radio-group

I have a page in apache-wicket-7 with RadioGroup. I want to call a method in the backend Page class with ajax. To do this, I add the:

```
AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior
```

The code:

```
this.listInput = new RadioGroup<T>("radioGroup", this.model);
       this.listInput.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget arg0) {
                System.out.println("The selected value is " + getComponent().getDefaultModelObjectAsString());
            }
        });
```

The component RadioGroup becomes visible after an earlier ajax call, so it is also rendered asynchronously. But when wicket tries to render the component, the error message appears:

```
Wicket.Ajax:  Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "radioGroup1d" because the element is not in the DOM
```

Adding:

```
setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)
```

does nothing.
How this can be fixed?

Regards,
Mateusz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't use `<wicket:cotainer>` for it in the HTML template. Those are not rendered.

Comment: Well... there is actually `<wicket:container>`. I'm affraid I cannot change it, as this is already a provided component. Anyway thanks for advice, Martin